# error when i use this comment Ionic cordova build android in ionic 9

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

Generating ES5 bundles for differential loading...
An unhandled exception occurred: [BABEL] C:\Projects\ionic1\myApp\www\common-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-numeric-separator". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\Projects\ionic1\myApp\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js")
See "C:\Users\ichehade\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-xA10Tn\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
    ng.cmd run app:ionic-cordova-build --platform=android exited with exit code 127.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

PS C:\Projects\ionic1\myApp\platforms\android>

Comment: Hi Ibrahim and welcome to stack overflow! 

If you are seeking help with your code then you should include a minimal reproducible example in your post because the description " An unhandled exception occurred" is not diagnostically useful. Did you rerun the command with the `--verbose` flag as recommended? Could you provide some code? How does the `./available-plugins.js` file look like? Did you intentionally install the `proposal-numeric-separator`?

Please read stackoverflow.com/help/asking and update your question with meaningful information.

Answer (score 0):

Please use and install below library

> npm install @babel/compat-data@7.8.0

to devDependencies. It will save your time and efforts